# Show a sub-section of a rails site under a different domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple rails app for a side project where each product basically gets it's own controller and views. I've got refinerycms set up to serve the pages and this is all work great. However, for marketing purposes, I'd like to show each product under it's own domain.

For example, company.com/game-product should be visible from game-product.com.

I *don't* want to just redirect game-product.com to company.com/game-product. I'd like game-product.com to appear to the end user basically as it's own standalone site. I don't want to split them into separate rails sites as I'd have to duplicate a lot of CMS stuff and then manage several apps processes. Is there a way that I can just tell rails to generate links relative to game-product.com when the request comes in over game-product.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rails 3 you can work with constraints in your routes.

First you let all domains point to the same application.

Second, you catch the domains in your routes.rb

```
constraints :host => 'game-product.com' do
  root :to => 'controller-for-game-product#view'
end
```

:host checks the entire host name (subdomains + domainname) so include the www if necessary

You can also check in your controller/view for the host name (@request.host) if you need to change actions/views depending on the hostname.

Comment: Will this then also generate correct links using link_to and such?